# Sending and Receiving SMS using Twilio

Tags: php, twilio

I am developing an application for sending SMS through my website. I have three fields in my website 
          1) Name
          2) Mobile Number
          3) Message
When an user enters his name, mobile number and message the message need to be send to my Twilio number which I got after creating an account in Twilio (which is a trial account).
When I receive this message from the user I need to sent an automated reply to the number which he enter in the mobile number field.
How is it possible to achieve this functionality. Please help me out here.

Thanks

Comment: in my humble opinion you need to have a gateway with any of the operators to send SMSes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done quite easily using Twilio APIs. On your Twilio Control Panel, you set a phone number (or buy a new one from Twilio) which will receive replies from your clients. From the Control Panel, you'll have to link this phone number to a PHP script (sample given below). You have to write your own PHP script and host it on your server. This script will act as the SMS auto-responder. When a client sends you an SMS, Twilio makes an HTTP request to your URL (PHP script) with the body of the message and the sender's phone number. Your PHP script then can respond to the SMS by returning a reply message in the HTTP response to Twilio.

Sample PHP script:

```
<?php
    header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>
    <Sms>Thank you</Sms>
</Response>
```

Complete [reference available here](http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/hello-monkey).